# NodeJS with MySQL - Return blank Array

Tags: mysql, node.js, arrays

I have initialized an array "userTasklist". I have pushed the object in this array in .map function. After .map, I have console this Array but array is blank.

Than I have console the object in .map function and all the value print successfully but in Array there are no value. Don't know why.

```
exports.allUserList = (req, res) => {
    let userID = req.params.userid;
    const ghusersQuery = "SELECT user_id, name, employee_code FROM users WHERE under_gh = ?";
    conn.query(ghusersQuery, [userID], (err, userdata) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send({ message: err })
        } else {
            if (userdata && userdata.length > 0) {
                let userTasklist = [];
                userdata.map((datauser) => {
                    var objtask = {};
                    const userDataQuery = "SELECT * FROM tasklist WHERE user_id = ?";
                    conn.query(userDataQuery, [datauser.user_id], (errnew, taskdata) => {
                        if (taskdata && taskdata.length > 0) {
                            objtask = {
                                userid: datauser.user_id,
                                tasklist: taskdata
                            }
                            userTasklist.push(objtask);
                        }
                    })
                })
                console.log(userTasklist)
                res.send({ message: "user list fetched", userdata: userdata, tasklistdata: userTasklist })
            } else {
                res.send({ message: "Data not found!" })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: userTasklist is sent empty, before queries' callbacks are called. I'd recommend using running queries as a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which results you can [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Comment: can you please explain in details.. I am new in NodeJS

Comment: The problem is, userDataQuery's function is called after userTasklist. Have a look at this article on [avoiding this so called callback hell](https://medium.com/node-js-turkey/callback-vs-promises-vs-async-await-2c050206b890) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simplified solution using [mysql21](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql21) for handling queries as Promises.

```js
exports.allUserList = async (req, res) => {
  const { userid } = req.params
  const users = await connection.query('SELECT user_id, name, employee_code FROM users WHERE under_gh = ?', [userid])
  if (!users.length)
    return res.send({ message: "Data not found!" })
  
  // better fetch all relevant tasks in bulk
  const tasks = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM tasklist WHERE user_id IN (?)', [users.map(r => r.user_id)])
  res.send({ message: "user list fetched", users, tasks })
}
```

Comment: If I need bulk data, than my code is working fine without Async and await. I need data in separate separate Array.

Comment: Can you show a sample of expected result? You can reorganise the output in your app, but I'd generally avoid calling queries in a loop (like 200 queries for 200 users) as it may cause some serious overhead.

Comment: I have group head and team members in users table. Team members add Task list 3 times a day @12PM, 3PM, and 6PM. Now group head see the last 7 days Task list of team members...... So I want to loop 7 days date first and list on top of the table, after that I want to show the 12PM, 3PM and 6PM time below the date and after that I want to show the all team members of logged in group head in left side in <td> and these team members fetched from the users array (first query execute) and than I want to show the task list for every team members in respective time 12PM, 3PM and 6PM.........

Comment: So at React end I have first .map() function for 7 days and inside this loop I have another second .map() function for list team members and after that I have third .map() function for list the task list.